# Collapse columns into a new variable

Tags: r, merge, multiple-columns

I have a data frame that looks like this.

```
name = c("p1","p2","p3","p4")
place = c("f","g","h","i")
v1 = c("x", "NA", "NA", "NA")
v2 = c("NA", "y", "y", "NA")
v3 = c("NA", "NA", "z", "NA")
region = c("n","w","s","e")
grade = c("f1","f2","f3","f4")
df = data.frame(name, place, v1, v2, v3, region, grade)

  name place v1 v2 v3 region grade
1   p1     f  x NA NA      n    f1
2   p2     g NA  y NA      w    f2
3   p3     h NA  y  z      s    f3
4   p4     i NA NA NA      e    f4
```

I would like to add a new character vector v4 that contains the character from any of columns v1 v2 v3.

```
  name place v1 v2 v3 v4 region grade
1   p1     f  x NA NA  x      n    f1
2   p2     g NA  y NA  y      w    f2
3   p3     h NA  y  z yz      s    f3
4   p4     i NA NA NA NA      e    f4
```

many thanks

Comment: Please don't use quotes on `"NA"`.  It should be `NA`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `paste` after converting the columns to `character`

```
df$V4 <-  gsub("NA", "", do.call(paste, c(df[3:5], sep="")))
df$V4[df$V4==""] <- NA
df$V4
#[1] "x"  "y"  "yz"  NA
```

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(name = c("p1", "p2", "p3", "p4"), place = c("f", 
"g", "h", "i"), v1 = c("x", NA, NA, NA), v2 = c(NA, "y", "y", 
NA), v3 = c(NA, NA, "z", NA), region = c("n", "w", "s", "e"), 
grade = c("f1", "f2", "f3", "f4")), .Names = c("name", "place", 
"v1", "v2", "v3", "region", "grade"), class = "data.frame",
 row.names = c("1", "2", "3", "4"))
```

Answer (score 0):

The dplyr alternative:

```
install.packages("dplyr")
library(dplyr)
df <- df %>%
      mutate( v4 = gsub( "NA", "", paste0(v1,v2,v3) ) ) %>%
      mutate( v4 = ifelse( v4 == "", NA, v4 ) )
```

This should work if NA/"NA" is NA (not-a-value) or "NA" (character). And if you don't care whether v4 contains "" or NA, you can leave off the last line (and delete the last pipe).